# Want to create python API and integrated with swagger/postman

Tags: python, performance, rest, flask, google-bigquery

Requirement: 1. I want to create `python API` which will help to insert data in big query table and this API will host in swagger/postman, from there user can provide input data so that it will get reflected in big query table.

Can anyone help me to find out suitable solution with code

```
import sqlite3 as sql
from google.cloud import bigquery
from google.oauth2 import service_account
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file('path/to/file.json')

project_id = 'project_id'
client = bigquery.Client(credentials= credentials,project=project_id)
def add_data(group_name, user_name):  
  try:
    # Connecting to database
    con = sql.connect('shot_database.db')
    # Getting cursor
    c =  con.cursor() 
    # Adding data
    job_config.use_legacy_sql = True
    query_job = client.query("""
    INSERT INTO `table_name` (group, user) 
    VALUES (%s, %s)""",job_config = job_config)
    
    results = query_job.result() # Wait for the job to complete.
    # Applying changes
    con.commit() 
  except:
    print("An error has occured")
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you provided is a mix of **SQLite** and **BigQuery**, but it likes that you're trying to use **BigQuery** to insert data into a table. To insert data into a BigQuery table using Python, you can use the **insert_data()** method of the Client class. Here's I am adding an example of how you can use this method to insert data into a table called **"mytable"** in a dataset called **"mydataset"**:

```
# Define the data you want to insert
data = [
    {
        "group": group_name,
        "user": user_name
    }
]

# Insert the data
table_id = "mydataset.mytable"
errors = client.insert_data(table_id, data)

if errors == []:
    print("Data inserted successfully")
else:
    print("Errors occurred while inserting data:")
    print(json.dumps(errors, indent=2))
```

Then, You can create an API using **Flask** or **Django** and call the **add_data** method which you have defined to insert data into big query table.